# Type mismatch: inferred type is LoginActivity but LifecycleOwner was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack, android-architecture-components

I am playing with the preview version of `AndroidStudio - 3.4 Canary 9`.

I selected the default login activity option from `Configure your project` window and provided, selected below options:

[image: Configure your project]

No error reported on Gradle sync, however on build compilation it produces following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is LoginActivity but LifecycleOwner was expected
```

Here is the code snippet on which it is showing the error:

```
// Type mismatch at this@LoginActivity, required LifeCycleOwner, found - LoginActivity
        loginViewModel.loginFormState.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
            val loginState = it ?: return@Observer

            // disable login button unless both username / password is valid
            login.isEnabled = loginState.isDataValid

            if (loginState.usernameError != null) {
                username.error = getString(loginState.usernameError)
            }
            if (loginState.passwordError != null) {
                password.error = getString(loginState.passwordError)
            }
        })
```

`LoginActivity` is derived from `AppCompatActivity()`

Respective imported library is `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

Here is content from app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.socialsample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Here is content from Project level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha09'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Am I missing anything over here? Please suggest.

Comment: What class your Activity is inherited from?

Comment: LoginActivity is derived from AppCompatActivity().
Respective imported library is androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: I didn’t dig deep, but just explicitly added “implements LifecycleOwner” to my activity class works fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same issue and fix it with updating my support version to

`versions.support = "1.1.0-alpha01"`

so which means just update the

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'`

and it should be fixed

Comment: alpha02 is out now

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`

It won't work for you as **LifeCycleOwner** is not implemented.
Your AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity which further extends ComponentActivity and ComponentActivity implements LifeCycleOwner which is not in 1.0.2 version so upgrading (1.1.0-alpha02) or downgrading (1.0.0) will work for you.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Small typo: 1.1.0-alpha2 -> should be 1.1.0-alpha02

Answer (score 4):

It seems `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` doesn't implement `LifecycleOwner` interface in the version you are using **androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2**.

`android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` implicitly implements `LifecycleOwner`, so you need to inherit from it instead of `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`:

```
class LoginActivity : android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity() { ... }
```

or use some other `Activity` class that implements (explicitly or implicitly) `LifecycleOwner`, e.g. `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

Additionally, any custom application class can implement the `LifecycleOwner` interface. More info about `LifecycleOwner` is [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lco).

Comment: No idea.. your answer looks reasonable to me, marking it as accepted and upvoted from my end. In case if someone has alternate view points please feel free to add a comment or another answer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I have used androidx previously and it worked fine this is not the right answer.

Comment: @Arutha this is one of the possible solutions, if it is not working for you please leave a comment.